# Proper way to do clean up in servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, servlets

I need to release some resources in my web application (Tomcat 7).
I try to do it in the `destroy` of my `servlet`.
The problem is that when I do `getServletContext()` in my `destroy` nothing happens.
By debugging I managed to see:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:125)

Originating from my line `getSerlvetContext()` in the `destroy` method of my `servlet`.

So right now, I have no idea how am I supposed to do clean up in my web application.
I have stored some resources in the `ServletContext` so that it can be used from anywhere in my application and as far as I know 
the resource clean-up should be done either

1)  in the `destroy` of `servlets` or
2) the `contextDestroyed` of an `ServletContextListener`

But neither of these seem to work properly. In case (1) I get the `NullPointerException` when trying to access servlet context.
In case (2) the web application is already shutdown so if I have static methods responsible to do e.g. reallocation of DB connections etc the classes (as I have understood the problem) have already been unloaded by the JVM since the web app has been already shutdown.

Am I doing something wrong? What should I be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `ServletContext`, the usual way is to store it in an instance variable. Depending on whether you extend `Servlet` or implement a `ServletContextListener`, I would recommend to create an instance variable for the context and then store it from one of these methods:

- `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)`: Use `sce.getServletContext()` to obtain a reference of the context, which you can then store in an instance variable.
- `HttpServlet.init(ServletConfig config)`: Call the super method (`init`) with the `config` param, so you can later access it using `getServletContext()`. If that doesn't work, you can store the context in an instance variable using `config.getServletContext()`.

Answer (score -5):

With Hope. Really you need not worry about the cleanup process of TOMCAT/J2EE application process.If incase you are interested for doing this then simply delete/clear the Catalina temp directory.It is quite simple delete/clear all your working data and make your application new.Actually  when you run a web application tomcat create a temporary working directory inside the installation folder.So , follow the steps below:-

Steps:-

1. Stop your tomcat
2. Go to your tomcat directory ( C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5)
3. Find the work folder & delete (shift delete)

Now start the tomcat once again & Enjoy your new fresh application.

Have a happy Programming with TOMCAT.Any other follow my blog.

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to my question?